# How to get crc of input stream and return clone of this is

Tags: java, inputstream

I have one input stream. First I need to get crc of this is what I know how to do eg:

```
 CRCUtils.getCRC32(IOUtils.toByteArray(is))
```

I have method in crcUtils which can calculate it from byte array. But then I need  this input stream again and I cant use previous one because it reach end. So is there option how to get crc and clone of is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as such:

```
byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
CRCUtils.getCRC32(byteArr);
InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [CheckedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedInputStream.html) to compute the CRC while reading a stream:

```
CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
try (InputStream in = new CheckedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile"), crc)) {
    // read the input ...
}
// now crc contains the checksum of the input
long crc32 = crc.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the CRC value before processing the file, you could also make a subclass of [`FilteredInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) that passes everything it reads to a CRC32, with some bonus methods for getting the CRC value.

Comment: Thank you. You got me on the right track. Corrections: 1) You got the class name slightly wrong its the java.io.FilterInputStream (without the 'ed') and 2) java.io.CheckedInputStream allready does everything (the inheritance and the calculation) as described in the the other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467943/406423

Answer (score 0):

You could use [marks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29) in the input stream, if supported.